# How can I make my iPhone app use the whole screen (no status bar)?

Tags: iphone

How can I make my iPhone app use the full screen? I don't want to see time and signal bar.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for editing, what how can I ?

Answer (score 2):

1. The interface builder by default creates 460*320 view.... change that to 480*320 and align the views....
2. Set the property in your plist.info for UIStatusBarHidden to true.

Comment: but I am not using interface builder, so how to manually change the view ?

Comment: set the frame to view.frame = CGRectmake(0,0,480,320) for landscape or CGRectmake(0,0,320,480) for portrait.

Comment: @Veer If you aren't using IB, then you need to check your layout code.

Comment: It is not working, I am using UITabBarController, might be a reason

Answer (score 0):

Set the property in your plist.info for `UIStatusBarHidden` to `true`.

Comment: It made it hidden but my app is still on same position, now?, means it made that area with white color, I want my app on that are

Comment: @Veer If you have the layout for your application set in a xib file, you need to make sure it works correctly without a status bar. Check if the xib looks correct when the "simulated metrics" for the status bar is set to none.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also do that by changing the info.plist file.

I added a line, for 
"status bar is initially hidden" and checked the box next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```